# Is it possible to remove mouse pointer bounds (i.e. wrap the screen)?

Tags: xorg, mouse, pointers

I wonder it is possible to remove mouse pointer bounds. I mean when I move mouse pointer to right side of screen, I want it appear on left side. Also same thing for top/bottom bounds. To be clarify, you may think it like snake game without screen walls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've put up an easier-to-install version on my github [here](https://github.com/joshumax/taralli), you can install it using:

```
$ ./configure
$ make
$ make install
```

---

(original answer)

I believe using [Taralli](https://github.com/kmcallister/taralli) would allow for such a thing to happen with multiple workspaces...

There's some more info about what it is [here](http://mainisusuallyafunction.blogspot.com/2012/09/taralli-screen-edge-pointer-wrapping.html) and it seems to be what you're looking for. Compilation is easy and should work on regular rectangular screens by running

```
$ ./build.sh rectangular
$ # Note: if the above command fails try 'gcc -O2 -Wall -std=c99 -pedantic -o taralli_rectangular main.c map_rectangular.c -lX11 -lXi'
$ ./taralli_rectangular
$ sudo mv taralli_rectangular /usr/bin/taralli_rectangular
```

and then setting the binary to run on boot.

If you get the errors like:

```
In file included from main.c:1:0:
common.h:5:19: fatal error: X11/X.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/X.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
In file included from map_rectangular.c:1:0:
common.h:5:19: fatal error: X11/X.h: No such file or directory
 #include <X11/X.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
```

Install these dev packages:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev libxext-dev libxi-dev
```

And run the compilation steps again.

Comment: I have tested this, it works nicely.

Comment: Very nice. works even better :)

Comment: Unbelivably beautiful.  Thank you for this gem.  It works equally well when I have two monitors side by side my one workspace.

Answer (score 5):

You can use **brightside** to accomplish this, It has a option to wrap around when you mouse hits a screen edge.

1. Install brightside with:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install brightside
   ```
2. In terminal run:

   ```
   brightside-properties
   ```
3. This box should then appear:

[image]

Lasstly Check the boxes that say:

> **[✓]** Switch to adjacent workspace when mouse is moved to edge of screen
>   **[✓]** When switching workspace, wrap around edges of workspace layout

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly what I wanted. I dont want to switch workspace.

Comment: @ibrahim: Technically, you're switching from workspace 1 to workspace 1, so you aren't switching workspaces.

Comment: You are right If I have one workspace, but I am using four workspace