# Mouse cursor 360 degree

Tags: mouse, games, screen, chromeos

Is there a way to set mouse work like this: If i move cursor to one side of edge of screen instead of stopping it came out from opposite side of screen.
I have pretty good reason for this.

I am trying to play game on chrome OS in android and using octopus keymapper but mouse stuck on edge of screen.

Comment: So... You want to play Portal without playing Portal?

Comment: I am trying to play game on chrome OS in android and using octopus keymapper but mouse stuck on edge of screen.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have one workspace only, you can install [brightside](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/brightside). If you are in Bionic you won't find it in repositories.
I test it in Ubuntu Bionic (18.04) with the xenial (16.04) and worked so you can download directly from the previous link.

More info: [Is it possible to remove mouse pointer bounds (i.e. wrap the screen)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445481/is-it-possible-to-remove-mouse-pointer-bounds-i-e-wrap-the-screen)